# Java Spring boot Api : Controller behavior depending on query parameter

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, design-patterns, solid-principles

Basically I am forced to use a path url as follows

`GET /accounts/<accountNumber::string>/reports?type=<DAILY>&date=<YYYY-MM-DD>`

The thing is that my behaviour is highly dependent of my report type, as you can see "Daily" in my example. So i am looking for a design pattern that would allow me to simulate a controller factory that would instantiate specific controllers for each of my reports types.
For example i would have a DefaultController having a method called getReport that would be mapped to my GET request and that would delegate to other specific controllers (i.e: DailyReportController) the task of generating and returning the report.

I want my design to be as reliant as possible to on the SOLID principles and other clean code and maintainability principles. So even if i would add a report type in a month, all it would take me is adding a new TypeReportController and a value in my ReportType enum, and not having infinite methods in my controller and my services

Comment: Just create a controller mapping for each report value and handle the logic in there. What's the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I have Read your description. But I think there can be one controller endpoint and the your controller will choose different service implementation. Like if you parameter is **DAILY** then it will choose **DailyReportServiceImpl** and choose other implementation depends on your Report type. You can try following design:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    ReportService reportService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/accounts/{accountNumber}/reports")
    public Report getReport(@PathParam("accountNumber") String accountNumber,
                              @RequestParam("type") String type,@RequestParam("date")Date date){

        if(ReportEnum.DAILY.name().equals(type))
        {
            reportService = new DailyReportServiceImpl();
        }else if(ReportEnum.MONTHLY.name().equals(type)){
            reportService = new MonthlyReportService();
        }
        return reportService.getReport();
    }
}
```

And Declare a interface for Services:

```
public interface ReportService {
    public Report getReport();
}
```

And then implement this service from dailyreportservice and other services:
**DailyReportServiceImpl**  will be like this :

```
public class DailyReportServiceImpl implements ReportService {
    @Override
    public Report getReport() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MonthlyReportService**  will be like this :

```
public class MonthlyReportService implements ReportService {
    @Override
    public Report getReport() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Declare a Report class :

```
public class Report {
}
```

then you need to define a enum :

```
public enum ReportEnum {
    DAILY("DAILY"),
    MONTHLY("MONTHLY"),
    YEARLY("YEARLY");

    private String name;

    ReportEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

**NB:**: Anyway do you specific reason to define different controller endpoint?

If Yes you can define endpoints another way : like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    ReportService reportService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/accounts/{accountNumber}/reports/DAILY")
    public Report getReportDaily(@PathParam("accountNumber") String accountNumber,
                              @RequestParam("date")Date date){
        reportService = new DailyReportServiceImpl();
        return reportService.getReport();
    }
    @GetMapping(value = "/accounts/{accountNumber}/reports/MONTHLY")
    public Report getReportMonthly(@PathParam("accountNumber") String accountNumber,
                              @RequestParam("date")Date date){
        reportService = new MonthlyReportService();
        return reportService.getReport();
    }
}
```

But I think previous one is best design.

Comment: Terrible idea. A controller is a singleton - two requests at the same time will cause catastrophic failure.

Comment: which one? last or previous

Comment: The main body of the answer, where you suggest assigning a field from within a request mapping.

Comment: Do you read full answer? and end part of answer? I just define possibility for last one but also specify its not best.

Comment: "_But I think previous one is best design_" - exactly, you specify that the not working, not threadsafe suggestion is "best".

Comment: please propose a best design that will help us.

Comment: there is nothing about design that you were mentioned...